# changing background-color has no effect

Tags: html, css, background-color

I can't change the background color with my css stylesheet.

Here is the HTML (using Django); there are at present three listings in listings.

```
{% for listing in listings %}
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><img src="{{ listing.pic}}"> {{ listing }}</li>
        <div class="item-description">{{ listing.description }}</div>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
padding: 10px;
background-color: green !important;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: green !important;
}
.item {
    background-color: blue !important;
    height: 200px;
}
.item-description {
    background-color: purple !important;
}
```

As you can see I have already tried adding !important and giving elements a height. There is also a link for bootstrap which I tried deleting. However, nothing has any effect; the page and all elements remain white.

Comment: A `div` inside a `ul` is not valid html. If everything is white, are you sure that data is coming through? Check dev tools (F12).

Comment: I am sure that yesterday the bullet points in my list were gone but today they are here. It seems like the only thing actually getting through is the padding in body but why?